# Entity Framework database-first approach conditionally insert data

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework, how can I insert data if it does not exist, and update a field if it does?

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string odatacontext { get; set; }
    public Value[] value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SubmissionDate { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

To retrieve all the data from my API I use

```
root.value.Select(x => new satiaL
{ 
    accountID = x.AccountID,
    subDate = x.SubmissionDate,
    x_status = x.Status
});
```

which of course will insert all records.

If the `AccountID` already exists in the database, I want to update the value of `x_status`, but if the `AccountID` does NOT yet exist in the database, then I want to insert all values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not.

Upsert functionality is not part of an object/relational model - objects are there or not, and tracked by identity. Thre is no "update if it is not there" concept - at all. So, there is nothing for EfCore to implement.

This smells like abusing an ORM as a ETL loader, and this is not what you should do - ETL (mass data loading) is not what and ORM is made for. Time to write your own method to move data up into tables and possibly do upswert there. Did that years ago, comes really handy at times.

Right now all you can do is run a lot of finds for every account and basicalyl write code: create if not exists, update if exists.

Pseudocode:

```
var account = Find ( select ) or default from db
if account == null create
else update
savechanges
```

Something along this line. Beware of performance - you may want to just builk load all accounts. Beware of conflicting updates.